# How can I fix crash reported by user of app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

A user is reporting a crash in my app but I can't seem to recreate it and have not heard of this crash from any other users. He claims the app crashes when he comes back to it after using different apps. There are no crash reports on iTunes connect either and hes using the latest device and os.

Comment: not much you can do unless you get logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the user follow the directions here:

http://www.ispeeddial.com/how-to-find-the-crash-log-for-an-iphone-application/

Answer (score 1):

You should not worried about it much. There are many SDk around which allow user to submit there bugs/feedback direct to developer rather than on itune store. There may be several reason either he/she put down your app(marketing strategy). But the nicer solution is i can tell you that somehow may depend of your code may be related the memory leak. If you are confident with your coding standard then finally you should not worry about until unless many people does not complain about it